# ASP.NET Upload size limit

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I tried to modify the upload size limit in the project's Web.config
Adding the lines:

```
<system.web>

<httpRuntime 
  maxRequestLength="512000"
  executionTimeout="3600"
/>
  ...

</system.web>

 <system.webServer>
 ...
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="15728640" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Like I found in most places.
But when I try to upload it still doesn't work.
When I try to upload it gives me the following error:

> > Server Error in '/' Application. Maximum request length exceeded. Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
> >     the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
> >     information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Maximum request length
>   exceeded.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Maximum request length exceeded.]
>   System.Web.HttpRequest.GetEntireRawContent() +9904940
>   System.Web.HttpRequest.GetMultipartContent() +63
>   System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection() +160
>   System.Web.HttpRequest.EnsureForm() +69
>   System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form() +13
>   System.Web.HttpRequestWrapper.get_Form() +14
>   System.Web.Mvc.HttpRequestExtensions.GetHttpMethodOverride(HttpRequestBase
>   request) +121
>   System.Web.Mvc.AcceptVerbsAttribute.IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, MethodInfo methodInfo) +37
>   System.Web.Mvc.HttpPostAttribute.IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, MethodInfo methodInfo) +39
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodSelectorBase.IsValidMethodSelector(ReadOnlyCollection`1
>   attributes, ControllerContext controllerContext, MethodInfo method)
>   +54    System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodSelectorBase.RunSelectionFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, List`1 methodInfos) +118
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodSelectorBase.FindActionMethods(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName) +166
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodSelectorBase.FindActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName) +31
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.ReflectedAsyncControllerDescriptor.FindAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName) +54
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.FindAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, String
>   actionName) +203
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object
>   state) +136
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1c(AsyncCallback
>   asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +25
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object callbackState) +30
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback,
>   Object state) +465
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__14(AsyncCallback
>   asyncCallback, Object callbackState, Controller controller) +18
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object callbackState) +20
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext,
>   AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +374
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.BeginExecute(RequestContext
>   requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +16
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__4(AsyncCallback
>   asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ProcessRequestState innerState) +52 
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object callbackState) +30
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +384
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext,
>   AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +48
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +103    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +48    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
>   step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +159

Comment: How big is your file?

Comment: @abney317 the files are around 5-15 MB

Comment: Are you making sure to edit the main web.config file and not one in a different folder (like the views folder)

Comment: @abney317 that's exactly what I did, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As resolved in my comment above, you should make sure to edit the main web.config file and not the one in the Views folder if you're working with MVC.